# Print OpenLayers Map AND Additional Divs

Tags: openlayers

I have an application with an embedded OpenLayers map. The map contains a base layer plus several Feature layers with graphics, etc.

I need a way to create a printout that includes the map and also other items such as a legend, title, data table, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

I've thought of creating a pop-up window; however, I can't find any way to clone the map itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) you just give it a div and get a png. great for reports that look just like what the user sees on the page!

Comment: I gave html2canvas a try. It prints the map controls; however neither the map tiles from Google nor any of my Features are printed.

Comment: @Frank Conry ,html2canvas does not print or takes map layers when creating screen shot of the page.